# Is the usage of the phrase "as if in a mirror" correct?

Tags: grammar

> The evil, twisted will from which the striga was born. The witcher
>   shivered at the memory of taking on that evil to redirect it, **as if
>   in a mirror**, against the monster.

The above is from the Witcher, the book with the short stories, and I was wondering if it was a correct usage and if you would criticize such usage. If not, could you explain to me why this is correct, and give me some examples for me to understand when I can use such a wording?

I am asking the question here, because I would like to know when I can use such a phrasing myself and the phrasing sounds odd to my ears as I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: Bearing in mind that *The Witcher* was originally written in Polish, this looks like a poor translation. Is this from an official English version of the novel, or your own attempt at translating a Polish idiom from the book into English?

Comment: It's from the official translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole thing is a total mess.

Basically, your instinct is correct.  DO NOT WRITE SENTENCES LIKE THAT.

If a reasonably intelligent person has trouble understanding a sentence after reading it a couple of times, it should be rewritten. In the real world, grammatical legitimacy/correctness means nothing.

Comment: I had to re-read your final paragraph a couple of times, but I think you're saying that one can ignore grammar rules if it makes your sentence clearer. Correct?

Comment: Interestingly, the "as if in a mirror" part deals no problem to me. However, I can imagine no situation where this phrase could be useful, because there are too few differences between image in the mirror and in the reality. Maybe if one describes a person who looks exactly as himself, of course... And regarding correctness: redirect something **in** a mirror? Sounds wrong.